# where is the memory map configuration stored?

Tags: memory, microcontroller

Assume there is an MCU(like a cypress PSOC4 chip which I'm using). It contains a flash memory(to store firmware) and a RAM(probably SRAM) inside the chip. I understand that even these two components need to be memory mapped in order for the processing unit to access them.

However, the flash memory and SRAM should be mapped every time the MPU is powered on, right?.

Then where is the configuration for memory map stored? 
Is it somehow hardwired inside the MPU? Or is it stored in a separately hidden small piece of RAM?

I once thought that the memory map info should be located at the front of the firmware, but this doesn't make sense because the firmware is stored in the flash, and the MPU would have no idea where the flash is mapped to. So, I think this is a wrong idea.

By the way, is a memory map even configurable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes hardwired in the mcu on boot, some mcus allow for remapping once up and running, but in order to boot the flash/rom has to be mapped to a known place, a sane design would also have the on chip sram mapped and ready to use on boot at a known location.

Some use straps (pins externally hardwired high or low) to manipulate how the mcu boots, sometimes that includes a different mapping.  A single strap could for example choose between mapping a bootloader rom vs the user flash into the boot space of the processor.  But that would be documented as with other mapping choices in the chip vendors documentation for the part.

Some mcus allow you to in software after boot move ram into the vector/exception table area so you can manipulate it at run time and not be limited to what was in the flash at boot.  Some mcus are going so far as to have a mmu like feature, but I have a hard time calling those mcus as they can run in the hundreds of mhz, have floating point uints, caches, etc.  Technically they are a SOC with ram and flash on chip, so classified as an MCU.

Your thinking is sane, the flash and sram mappings are in logic and at reset you can know where things will be.  It is in the documentation for that product.

Comment: thanks! I'll have to go and check out the documentation for my mcu : )